# Accessing a git repository through ssh-config

Tags: command-line, git, cygwin, ssh-config

I am trying to push to my git repository from cygwin but in vain. It used to work. I get

```
$ git push
ssh: Could not resolve hostname prooftheory: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now, my ssh-config file is readable for me

```
-rwxrwxr--+ 1 user Tartományfelhasználók 230 Dec 10  2015 /cygdrive/c/Users/user/.ssh/config
```

and it contains

```
Host phd
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User git

Host prooftheory
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pt_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    User git
```

.git/config contains, among other things:

```
[remote "origin"]    
        url = ssh://git@prooftheory/gergely_/prooftheory.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I can ping bitbucket.org . . What am I missing here?

EDIT

https://serverfault.com/questions/518729/cygwin-ssh-issue-could-not-resolve-hostname-awshost1-hostname-nor-servname-pro

says cygwin might get ssh config info from somewhere else but it is not clear how can I configure git to use ~/.ssh/config. I copied that config to ~/.ssh/ssh_config but that did not help. Unfortunately, ssh -vvv does not write which config file it reads.

Comment: What happens when you do `ssh prooftheory -vvv`?

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname prooftheory: Name or service not known -- how can I configure ssh to make it know?

Answer (score 1):

First I had to make a symlink from

```
/home/user
```

to

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/user
```

and, following

https://serverfault.com/questions/253313/ssh-hostname-returns-bad-owner-or-permissions-on-ssh-config

do a

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

and it made it work.

I still get

```
key_load_public: invalid format
```

errors but in spite of this, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git `GIT_SSH` variable with something like that `GIT_SSH="ssh -F ~/.ssh/config"` (and adapt paths for your Windows setup).